# How to display a specific event with perf report?

Tags: linux, performance, perf

I record several events using Linux `perf` tool with a command line similar to:

```sh
perf record --event cycles,LLC-load-misses,LLC-store-misses,L1-icache-load-misses command args
```

Then I use `perf report --stdio` to display the results. `perf report` displays a report for each event, one report after the other, thus if I want to check the measures for a specific event I have to scan the output for it.

Is there an option for `perf report` to display the measures for a specific event? I expected something like `perf report --event LLC-load-misses --stdio` but `report` does not accept `--event`.